# XSLT: rename XML attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

I've got the following XML

```
<message code="100" description="checkSnr">
 <string name="id" />
 <string name="serialNr" />
</message>
```

Now I basically want to rename

```
<string name="serialNr" />
```

into

```
<string name1="serialNr" />
```

I read all the other questions about this topic but none work for me.
The idea behind this is easy: The single strings are supposed to be different to each other. Example:

```
<xsl:value-of select="message/string/@name"  />
```

will be "id".

```
<xsl:value-of select="message/string/@name1"  />
```

will be "serialNr".
I want them to be listed in a CSV like "id;serialNr" my actual output without renaming the attributes is "id;id". If you've got any other ideas how to solve this problem, your solutions are appreciated aswell!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your title says "rename XML elements" yet the example you show renames a `name` attribute to `name1`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen whoops, seems like I was a little bit absentminded.

Comment: Are you saying that if you had a third `string` element, you would want it to be output as `<string name2="..." />`?

Comment: @TimC Yup, exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If @TimC has correctly guessed what your real requirements are, then you want

```
<xsl:template match="message">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="string"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="string">
  <string>
    <xsl:attribute name="name{position()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </string>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works wonderfully. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Ok, actually found a problem with your solution. It excludes the "message code" attribute which is necessary for the xml. Do you have any ideas how to include the code again?

Comment: I only gave you the part of the code that was relevant to solving your problem, I assumed the rest was trivial. Just add the relevant detail to the match="message" template.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="string/@name">
    <xsl:attribute name="name1">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That will rename `<string name="serialNr" />` as well, it is not clear whether that is wanted.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, it is a good starting point I reckon. OP can polish this solution as much as he/she wants, with no copyright issues :D